# Firefox 51.0.1 chrome://global/content/console.xul don't exist for XUL

Tags: firefox, console, xul

I work on a XUL firefox application and i need to debug it.
For debug i use the console that firefox give us.
In the **49.0.2** version of firefox :

> chrome://global/content/console.xul

exist in the zip file **omni.ja**
But since the **51.0.1** version of firefox : 
the folder "global" dosen't exist anymore.

I try to open

> chrome://devtools/content/webconsole/webconsole.xul

or

> chrome://devtools/content/webconsole/debugger.xul

but i have no results.

Someone had the same problem ?

PS : sorry for my english

Comment: Why are you opening the URL `chrome://global/content/console.xul` and not the [Browser Console](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Browser_Console) (Ctrl-Shift-J, or Cmd-Shift-J on OSX)?

Comment: I create my proper firefox application. I must create all the bind and the action else no keybind exist. You can see a part of code that i use here : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Archive/Mozilla/XULRunner/Debugging_XULRunner_applications